# How to use foreach inside Alert.alert in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, react-native, alert

```
function openmodal(modalarray) {
  return Alert.alert(
    "Alert Title",
    "My Alert Msg",
    [
      modalarray.forEach(element => {
        "{text: element, onPress: () => console.log('button press)},";
      })
    ],
    { cancelable: false }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use `.map` function instead of `.forEach`. `.forEach` doesn't return any value, hence you are just passing `undefined` in the array.

Consider the following example

```
function openmodal(modalarray) {
  return Alert.alert(
    "Alert Title",
    "My Alert Msg",
    [
      ...modalarray.map(element =>
        ({text: element, onPress: () => console.log('button press')}))
    ],
    { cancelable: false }
  );
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: is there a way to use nested map ?? i mean how can i nest a map inside another map ??

Comment: yes, you can if array elements are array itself, like `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function openmodal(modalarray) {
  return Alert.alert(
    "Alert Title",
    "My Alert Msg",
    modalarray.map(element => ({
      text: element,
      onPress: () => console.log('button press')
    })),
    { cancelable: false }
  );
}
```